# Finding all the integer solutions for :$y^2=x^6+17$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assume that $x,y$ are integers .How to find the solutions for:
$$y^2=x^6+17$$

Comment: First find all the solutions of $y^2=x^2+17$ --- that's easy --- and then it's easy to answer your question.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I don't care about the solutions .I care about the method to find them all .

Comment: I have given you a method to find them all.

Comment: x and y can be negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y^2-x^6=17\Rightarrow (y-x^3)(y+x^3)=17$.And we know $17$ is a prime.

So the only possibility is

$y+x^3=17$ and $y-x^3=1$ .

or $y+x^3=-17$ and $y-x^3=-1$

or $y+x^3=1$ and $y-x^3=17$

(As $x,y$ are integers so $(y-x^3)(y+x^3)=17$ implies that the only factors of $17 $ are $y+x^3$ and $y-x^3$ )

$\Rightarrow y=9,x=2$

or $y=9,x=-2$

or $x=-9,y=2$

or $x=-9,y=-2$

Comment: Not leaving much for OP to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have only found one solution right now.

$y=9,x=2$

And hope it may help you.

Comment: can you the steps involved?